# Get next char for R

Tags: r, list

I have a list identifying the variables of some network paths:

```
> List_path<-list(c("A", "B", "C"), c("B", "C", "D"))
> List_path
[[1]]
[1] "A" "B" "C"

[[2]]
[1] "B" "C" "D"
```

And also an adjacency matrix:

```
> MM<-matrix(c(1,1,0,0,0,-1,1,1,-1,0,0,-1,1,-1,0,0,-1,0,1,1,0,0,0,-1,1), 5, byrow=T)
> colnames(MM)<-c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E")
> row.names(MM)=colnames(MM)
> MM
   A  B  C  D  E
A  1  1  0  0  0
B -1  1  1 -1  0
C  0 -1  1 -1  0
D  0 -1  0  1  1
E  0  0  0 -1  1
```

I want to determine the sign of each path of the network by using the list of paths and the matrix. My idea is to create a condition where if a given *i* was followed (the exact variable after) by a given *j*, then they would form a pair *[i,j]*, and I could use this to get the information from my matrix.

Here follows more or less my idea in code:

```
if(List_path[[1]][j]  *follows* List_path[[1]][i]){
    List_report[[1]]=List_report[[1]]*MM[i,j]}
```

In this case, the List_report would already with 1´s for each element.

The `List_report` should be something like this:

```
 > List_report
[[1]]
[1] 1  # 1 (from original)* 1 (from [A,B]) * 1 (from [B,C])

[[2]]
[1] -1 # 1 (original) * 1 (from[B,C]) * -1 (from[C,D])
```

My question is, is there in R a function to get the variable right after the one I indicate, or the one right before?

I tried to look for this and only could find the `getnextchar` in other languages and no similar in R. If anyone could help, I would be most appreciated

Comment: I don't understand... why can't you simply use the index before or after : e.g. `i-1, i+1` ?

Comment: Is maybe this what you want ? `lapply(List_path,function(v)unlist(unname(Map(f=function(x,y)setNames(MM[x,y],paste0(x,'->',y)), head(v,-1),tail(v,-1)))))`

Comment: I tried the `List_path[[1]][j]==List_path[[1]][i+1]` but it would only give an error message saying that `missing value where T/F needed`. On the `lapply` idea, how would I visualise the result? Didn't got that part.

Comment: Actually, my lapply example should be self-explanatory (basically it should generate your List_report), but I admit is not completely clear to me what is your expected result. Could you please post the expected result, given your example input data ?

Comment: Ok, I saw now how your `lapply` works, but basically it only gives me the info on the sign (value of either 1 or -1) of each pair, which is what I already have in the matrix. What I what is to get the sign of the total path, that is *AB* * *BC* for example.

Comment: Plus, followed your tip and added the expected `List_report` has an example.

Comment: I posted an answer ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code :

```
res <- lapply(List_path,
              function(v) prod(unlist(Map(f=function(x,y)MM[x,y],head(v,-1),tail(v,-1)))))

> res
[[1]]
[1] 1

[[2]]
[1] -1
```

Comment: Thats it!! Thank you very much @digEmAll!!

Answer (score 1):

You could make your own `getnextchar` function. Here's a basic one for capital letters only:

```
getnextchar <- function( char ) {
    LETTERS[ which( LETTERS == char ) + 1L ]
}
```

Then, for example:

```
getnextchar("F")
[1] "G"
```

I should explain that `LETTERS` is a built in vector object of all the capital letters in the english language. `letters` is likewise the lower case alphabet.

Comment: I tried your function by applying it to my code in this way:
`if(List_path[[1]][j] == getnextchar(List_path[[2]][i])){ List_res[[1]]=List_res[[1]]*marcus[i,j]}`    
But all I get is a warning message of `missing values where T/F needed`. Not sure what is happening....